# Why does WebView elements still have Holo UI and how to change them?

Tags: android, material-design, android-theme, android-holo-everywhere

I have a webView in one of my Android apps with `setBuiltInZoomControls()` set to true but I see that the zoom control has Holo UI instead of Material:

[image]

What is the best way to change or customize this?

Answer (score 1):

By default Apps developer can't control these things, It is displayed according to certain features according to the Android version and the used theme in `styles.xml`

If you want to change Webview style only create programmatically and passed the appearance in the parameters

```
WebView WebView = new WebView(context, null, R.style.CustomStyle);
```